# Copy memory of a class with STL vector type member

Tags: c++

For a vector of size 5 of the following class,

```
struct Aclass
{
  double x;
  std::vector<double> y;
  Aclass(){}
  Aclass(double x, int ysize): x(x)
  {
    y.resize(ysize, x * ysize);
  }
};
```

I want to erase the 2nd element:

```
void eraseEle()
{
  std::vector<Aclass> v(5, Aclass(1, 3));


  // Erase the 2nd element
  {
    std::vector<double>(0).swap(v[2].y);
    // Copy the bits from &v[3] ~ &v[5] to &v[2]:
    std::memmove(&v[2], &v[3], sizeof(Aclass) * (v.size() - 3));
    v.resize(v.size() - 1);
  }
  

  // Print
  for(int i = 0, iend = v.size(); i < iend; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << v[i].x << ", " << v[i].y[0] << "\n";
  }
}
```

The method is quite nonstandard. `g++ 4.9.3 -O2` compiles it but the program always crashes at `std::memmove(...)`. Is it because the header of a STL vector is protected in some way that leads `std::memmove()` to trigger undefined behavior?

Thank you!

**A deeper answer**:

The reason for undefined behavior is that `.resize()` releases the container in `v[4]`, so afterwards, `v[3]` contains a `vector` header that points to nothing, raising undefined behavior when accessing vector elements. To really make it work, add

```
std::fill((char*)(&v.back().y), (char*)(&v.back().y) + 24, 0);
```

before `v.resize(v.size() - 1);`. The above prevents `.resize()` releasing the container memory by letting the last element (to be erased) contain a `vector` that points to nothing.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: You cannot copy a non-POD class with `memmove`.

Comment: not sure what your objective is but why dont you use `erase(v.begin()+1)`

Comment: You know that you can use `v.erase(v.begin() +1)` ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's surprising how often you actually can depending on compiler & os. Makes for all sorts of fun when you switch to a new toolchain. I've inherited some pretty janky code over the years. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) on `memmove` states that:

> If the objects are not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of memmove is not specified and may be undefined

And STL vector object is not a trivially-copyable object.

As suggested in one comment, the vector member function `erase` does what you want to do.

[Trivially-copyable](http://Every%20copy%20constructor%20is%20trivial%20or%20deleted%20%20Every%20move%20constructor%20is%20trivial%20or%20deleted%20%20Every%20copy%20assignment%20operator%20is%20trivial%20or%20deleted%20%20Every%20move%20assignment%20operator%20is%20trivial%20or%20deleted%20%20at%20least%20one%20copy%20constructor,%20move%20constructor,%20copy%20assignment%20operator,%20or%20move%20assignment%20operator%20is%20non-deleted%20%20Trivial%20non-deleted%20destructor%20%20This%20implies%20that%20the%20class%20has%20no%20virtual%20functions%20or%20virtual%20base%20classes.) objects are objects of classes where:

> - Every copy constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every move constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every copy assignment operator is trivial or deleted
> - Every move assignment operator is trivial or deleted
> - at least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is non-deleted
> - Trivial non-deleted destructor
>
> This implies that the class has no virtual functions or virtual base classes.
>   Scalar types and arrays of TriviallyCopyable objects are TriviallyCopyable as well, as well as the const-qualified (but not volatile-qualified) versions of such types.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I hesitated to use erase member function is that I was afraid it would trigger deep copy, which I haven’t examined. The reason I hesitated to do a loop of swaps is that it seemed still slow.. but I guess probably that’s the way to go now:)

Comment: "seemed still slow" != "actually slow" without measuring.